# Traveling to Puerto Rico as Student while waiting for OPT

Tags: usa, f1-visas, puerto-rico

I am an international student. I already finished my program and I am waiting to start my OPT. My I20 already expired and I am waiting for my EAD Card. I have a US valid Driver License. Can I travel to Puerto Rico?

Comment: I am asking because I do not have an  I-20. It just expired. I have a Driver License.

Comment: You don't need anything else for a domestic flight.